# Bind a collection to a WPF TabControl with static TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` with a couple of static `TabItems`. I am now trying to dynamically add some tabs with a custom `ItemTemplate` and `ContentTemplate`.
Something like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding DynamicTabs}">  
    <TabItem Header="Static 1">Content 1</TabItem>  
    <TabItem Header="Static2">Content 2</TabItem>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate> 
</TabControl>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [CompositeCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-a-compositecollection?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to combine your different sources:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DynamicTabsCollectionVS" Source="{Binding DynamicTabs}"/>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <TabItem Header="Static 1">Content 1</TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Static 2">Content 2</TabItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource DynamicTabsCollectionVS}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </TabControl.ItemsSource>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```